# Server Explorer keeps connecting to LocalDB

Tags: visual-studio-2015, localdb, server-explorer

I'm currently working on a project that makes use of LocalDb.  The application uses Entity Framework's `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` `DatabaseInitializer`, which causes the database to be dropped and recreated every time the application is run.

The problem is that Visual Studio's Server explorer will randomly connect to this LocalDb, which holds a connection open, preventing the database from being dropped and recreated properly.  Is there any way to stop the Server Explorer from connecting to my database automatically?  I have tried deleting the Server Explorer entry for it, but it just gets recreated when the application runs.

[image]